# How can I iterate a list of lists in Scala?

Tags: generics, scala, list

I am trying to implement my own generic flatten for list objects which hold lists in Scala. 
At this point I have

```
def myFlatten[T](list: List[List[t]]): List[T] = {
    for (xs <- list)
        for (x <- xs) yield x
}
```

I am getting a message:

> for xs found Unit required list.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
def myFlatten[T](list : List[List[T]]) = for(xs <- list; x <- xs) yield x
```

Answer (score 13):

Very close! Here's one that works:

```
scala> def myFlatten[T](list: List[List[T]]): List[T] = for (xs <- list; x <- xs) yield x 
myFlatten: [T](list: List[List[T]])List[T]
```

Or use the built-in `flatten`

```
scala> List(List(1, 2), List(3)).flatten
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> List(Set(1, 2), Set(3)).flatten  
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

It's instructive to see how to write this function without the `for` syntactic sugar.

```
scala> def myFlatten[T](list: List[List[T]]): List[T] = list flatMap identity
myFlatten: [T](list: List[List[T]])List[T]

scala> myFlatten(List(List(1, 2), List(3)))
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

**UPDATE**

BTW, the fact that `List[List[T]]` can be flattened to `List[T]` is 50% of the reason that `List` is a Monad. Generally, this is known as `join`. The other 50% comes from the fact you can map a function `A => B` across a `List[A]` to result in a `List[B]`. The general name for this is a `Functor map`. [fmap and join on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#fmap_and_join).

A different way of defining a Monad for type constructor `M` is with a `pure` operation, that takes a value of type `A`, and returns a `M[A]`; and a `bind` operation that takes an `M[A]`, a function `A => M[B]`, and results in `M[B]`. For Lists, `pure` == `List(_)`, and `bind` = `(l: List[A], f: (A => List[B])) => l.flatMap(f)`

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I like this style:

```
def myFlatten[T](list: List[List[t]]): List[T] = for {
  xs <- list
  x <- xs
} yield x
```